# Do I have to choose a specific zone in AWS PHP API?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

To run an instance with [run_instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonEC2/run_instances) I have to specify a placement because otherwise I get an error that the ami isn't available.
Now, there are multiple regions (such as `US East`, `US West` and so on) and multiple zones (such as `us-east-1a`, `us-east-1b` and so on) for every region.

Do I have to pass a specific zone to AWS or is it possible to just pass a region (like `us-east-1` maybe) and let Amazon chose the zone?
I'd like to keep that decision to Amazon because I don't see any difference between the zones and it would be a little bit more complex to equally distribute instances over all zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to specify the specific zone.

You can take some of the pain out of it by specifying launch configurations for autoscaling groups, rather than working strictly with individual instances. Launch configs can tell the system to run X instances in each of many zones.  This makes it easy to get the right number of instances you want in each zone, without having to hassle with actually instantiating each one. Additionally, you don't need to actually worry about "scaling" rules if you just want a fixed number of instances.

Here is some more background information

http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

Comment: thank you for your Answer. Autoscaling looks like the right solution for clustered servers. In my case, these machines are actually individual because they're launched for customers without High Availability and they won't be overloaded. So, in this case I have to think about some algorithm to equally distribute them, right? Do I have to distribute them over all zones or can I just put them in one zone and let the others be empty?

Comment: @wullxz So these are individual instances and not multiple instances per service?  In that case, you really don't gain anything by having your instances in multiple AZ's other than the additional effort to work in multiple AZ's.  Just because you are in a specific availability zone doesn't mean you are in a corresponding physical portion of the datacenter. You could have instances all in the same AZ in multiple physical locations across datacenters.  You would want to go multi-AZ once you are looking at load balancing traffic across multiple AZ's for better scaling and availability.

Comment: @wullxz Additionally, if any of these servers communicate with each other, you would save on bandwidth cost by having all servers in one AZ, vs. having servers communicate cross-AZ.

Comment: Ok, that makes my work a lot easier :) Thank you for your detailed answers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you have to specify the specific zone. And in your case , i see that you need solution for two problems :
-you need new instances for customers with low availability and also distribute them at different locations for performance - for which the best solution is - you can put load balancer over all the instances (single or multiple availability zones) and then connect cloudfront over the load balancers. Cloud front basically works in a way of content distribution and making your application highly available for different locations , hence improves the performance.